# save pictures to harddrive

Tags: c#, image, exception, invalid-argument

I'm trying to resize and safe a picture I've done some research and tried to get sommething working. Almost everythin works but the saving gaves me an invalid argument exception.
This is what I have:

```
     private void ResizeImage(Image image) 
     {
        int maxWidth = 100;
        int maxHeight = 100;
        int imageWidth = image.Size.Width;
        int imageHeight = image.Size.Height;

        double maxRatio = (double)maxWidth / (double)maxHeight;
        double picRatio = (double)imageWidth / (double)imageHeight;

        Image newImage = null;
        if (maxRatio > picRatio && imageWidth > maxWidth) 
        {
            newImage  = new Bitmap(image, new System.Drawing.Size(Convert.ToInt32(maxWidth / picRatio), maxHeight));            
        }
        else if (maxRatio < picRatio && imageHeight > maxHeight) 
        {
            newImage = new Bitmap(image, new System.Drawing.Size(maxWidth, Convert.ToInt32(maxHeight / picRatio)));         
        }

         // Encoder parameter for image quality
        EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality,1);

        // Jpeg image codec
        ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = this.getEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

        if(jpegCodec != null){
            EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
            newImage.Save(@".\temp\pdf\photos\test.jpg",jpegCodec,encoderParams);
        }   
    }

    private ImageCodecInfo getEncoderInfo(string mimeType) 
    {
        // Get image codecs for all image formats
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();

        // Find the correct image codec
        for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++) 
        {
            if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType) 
            {
                return codecs[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

But when I try to run it, it gives me an invalid argument exception on newImage.save()

Comment: You should make max width and max height arguments and set them to 100 at default, because from the outside no one would expect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882583.aspx), encoder quality parameter should be a 64-bit (long) value. Change this line:

```
var qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 1);
```

to

```
var qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 1L);
```

Comment: thx, it works, the quality however. Yeah well that's an other story

Comment: @jorne: I expect 1L to be horrible, since 100L is best quality (least compression).

Comment: yeah, just found that out. Tanks for the heads up1!